# Rollback synchronization using RestKit

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am building an app with synchronization support. Since the sync will require more than one request there is a risk of persistent errors during the sync (e.g. if some but not all of the requests fails).

**If anything goes wrong during the synchronization I want to rollback all changes so the synchronization is performed fully or not at all.**

It seems RestKit saves the managedObjectContext when it fetches data. This means I have no way of using an NSUndoManager to handle undo/rollbacks. What is the preferred way to do this? To backup the object store file (sqlite) and replace it if the synchronization fails would be one way but it does not seem very "pure".

Comment: Did you ever found a good solution?

Comment: I ended up performing a backup of the underlying store (sqlite) file and I recreate my PersistentStore if need to rollback. This solution is not perfect. For one thing it forced me to recreate all views in my app since managed object context is invalidated along with all managed objects.